# How to add parameter to Angular HTML element seletror directive?

Tags: html, angular, parameters, selector, directive

I have a simple directive which selector is an img.

```
@Directive(
  { selector: 'img' } 
)
export class ImageDirective {
...
}
```

How can I add boolean parameter to this directive?
I tried it with

```
@Input() enabled: boolean = false;
```

html part:

```
<img [enabled]="true"
```

but it does not work, does'nt matter what I set, the this.enabled remains false;

Thanks

Comment: do you want to just set an attribute for the img element?

Answer (score 0):

you should change your code:
in the directive change your selector:

```
selector:'[img]'
```

in the html change to

```
<p [enable] = true ></p>
```

Follow the explanation on [directive](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives)